# Get many results in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How to get many results in Sequelize in array? Example: I need get all values field `name` in table `test` and return this in console. I write:

```
test.findAll().them(function(result) {
    result.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item.name);
    });
});
```

How to get all values field `name` in array, without `forEach()`?

(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: Do you need to seach all results and projection column `name` or filter by `name`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` to pull out the names into an array.

```
test.findAll().then(function(result) {
    var names = result.map(function(item) {
        return item.name;
    });
    console.log(names);
});
```

If you're worried about the database returning other fields that you don't care about, you can use the `attributes` option for `findAll`, as [DevAlien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32673194/899801) mentioned:

```
test.findAll( {attributes: ['name']} ).then(function(result) {
    var names = result.map(function(item) {
        return item.name;
    });
    console.log(names);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
test.findAll({attributes: ['name']}).them(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: No, it is all results. I need only values field `name`.